# Get files from a page that is redirected using wget

Tags: linux, bash, http, redirect, wget

I am trying to download the contents of `http://someurl.com/123` using `wget`. The problem is that `http://someurl.com/123` is redirected to `http://someurl.com/456`.

I already tried using `--max-redirect 0` and this is my result:

```
wget --max-redirect 0 http://someurl/123
...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://someurl.com/456 [following]
0 redirections exceeded.
```

Is there a way to get the actual contents of `http://someurl.com/123`?

Comment: How do you know the content at the old url exists and is different from the redirected page?

Comment: I actually got the URL by viewing the files that are loaded in background.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `wget` can follow up to 20 redirections. But since you set `--max-redirect` to `0`, it returned `0 redirections exceeded`.

Try this command

```
wget --content-disposition http://someurl.com/123
```

> **--max-redirect=number**
>
> Specifies the maximum number of redirections to follow for a resource. The default is 20, which is usually far more than necessary. However, on those occasions where you want to allow more (or fewer), this is the option to use.
>
> **--content-disposition**
>   If this is set to on, experimental (not fully-functional) support for Content-Disposition headers is enabled. This can currently result in extra round-trips to the server for a HEAD request, and is known to suffer from a few bugs, which is why it is not currently enabled by default.

Comment: Sadly I'm still only getting the contents of the wrong page.

Comment: @Ramona Are you willing to share your url?

Comment: Sure https://www.strava.com/segment_efforts/11383221431 is redirected to https://www.strava.com/activities/474243846#11383221431

Comment: I was able to get it using the above command. My `wget` version is `GNU Wget 1.19.5 built on linux-gnu`

Comment: I am using wget for Windows und now also tried it on my Ubuntu subsystem, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Thank's anyway!